# What's the difference between низ and дно?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова

I understand both **низ** and **дно** mean *bottom*, but what is the difference between them in terms of usage? Is it simply that **дно** additionally or exclusively carries the meaning of *bottom surface*?

Comment: When you have a question like this, don't just use a Russian-English dictionary, try an [explanatory](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x) one.

Comment: Maybe someone could comment on the usage of донце and днище as well.

Comment: @ghostarbeiter, "донце" and "днище" both mean "bottom part" of some vessel. Usually it is not just an abstract "lower surface", but a material structural part of the object. For example, "There is some water left at the bottom of the barrell." -- "На дне (not "днище") бочки осталось немного воды". But "The bottom of the barrell is made of wood." -- "Днище бочки изготовлено из дерева" (but "дно" can be used here, as well). "Донце" is used for smaller vessels, such as a glass or a bottle, and "днище" -- for larger ones, like a ship, a car or a bath.

Comment: Also "днище" and "дно" (but not "донце") in gamers and teenager slang have a meaning "loser", "noob", when referred to people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right. **Низ** is a bottom, or the lower part of an object. **Дно** is a bottom, a surface. You can say низ дома, (the lower part of the house), but дно тарелки, бутылки, стакана, моря, океана (the bottom of the plate, bottle, glass, sea, ocean). **Вверх дном** means *upside-down*.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say "низ" (3d) is the lower part of an object, and "дно" (2d) the lower surface of an object.

Answer (score 2):

"Дно" is the bottom of a pan, for example, the bottom of the sea - the lowest part of the relief, object. Also, there's a figurative meaning - "the bottom of life," "the bottom of society", etc. (social bottoms)

The word "низ" is absolutely identical to the word "bottom".

Comment: I'm not sure about "absolutely identical", implying it isn't in the other case. The English *bottom* is just as much of a `дно` as a `низ`, including a metaphorical `дно`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an analogy:

1. в**низ**у - below;
2. на **дне** - at the bottom.

I would argue, that "дно" is a literal translation of "bottom", while "низ" is a general term for any surface that's below you (or in relation to some object).